# Facebook app policy inquiry

Tags: facebook, policy

for ads_read API it says "When in development mode, your app may only access ad accounts that are owned by admins of the app. This permission does not let you update, purchase, or modify ads."

Can someone clarify "owned by admins of the app". I have admin access to a business manager and admin access to ad accounts. Does this qualify? I ran a test and it appears to work but the language is confusing to me. If someone can help clarify exactly what this means and the limitations.

Thanks!